# Правильно "шести- и семилетние дети"?

Tags: числительные

Правильно с дефисом? Привык к такому написанию, но встретил без дефиса и засомневался. А где найти правило, не знаю.

Буду благодарен за ссылку, подтверждающую правильный вариант.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Правильно с дефисом?

Да, с дефисом. См. [**ПАС:**](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=59#pp59)

> § 112. Дефис применяется при записи конструкций с однородными членами,
>   имеющими общий конечный элемент, если все члены, кроме последнего,
>   представлены только начальными элементами; такой дефис называют
>   «висячим», напр.: *шарико-* и *роликоподшипники; лит-* и *изокружки;
>   кино-, теле-* и *видеофильмы...*

Comment: Спасибо, Слава!